# Ajax.beginForm() cannot get post value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, ajax.beginform

Guys. I Cannot get post value from ajax.beginform() when building mvc4 website. help me, thanks.:)

//View

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Ajax_Search_post", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ajax1"}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("search1")       
    <input type="submit" value="Ajax_Search" />
}    
    <div id="ajax1"></div>
```

//controler

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ajax_Search_post(string search1)
{  //..but i got search1=null here          
    return Content(search1);          
}
```

So, how can i get "search1" value?
PS: i can get "search1" value from 'get' method, but what about the 'post' way?

Comment: What you have shown should work fine.

Comment: specify httpmethod as well in ajaxoptions

Comment: Have you added the correct Ajax java scripts files?

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it will work.I couldn't see any other things missing in your code.

Comment: it is not linked with value posting, if unobtrusive not included in that case also form will post at least